# Finding coefficients of a polynomial expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

I am trying to find the coefficient of $x^{n}$ where $n \in[0, \infty)$ in the expansion

$(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 ... +x^{\infty}$)$^{t}$, where $t$ is an integer.

I haven't been able to distinguish a pattern between the coefficients and the value of $t$, but the sum $\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} x^i$ is the Taylor series expansion of the geometric sum formula. I also tried some things with the binomial theorem, but was not able to make too much progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $|x| < 1$ use GP sum and the expression reduces to,

$$(1-x)^{-t}$$

Coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-x)^{-t}$ equals $\binom{n+t-1}{t-1} = \binom{n+t-1}{n}$.

Check out the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^m$ when $m$ is negative.

Comment: What about the case for where $| x | > 1$? I tried to rewrite the sum as a binomial by expressing it as (1 + summation of rest)^t to use the binomial theorem, but I could not make much progress from there. I upvoted.

Comment: The expression in that case won't be nice. Not sure if it will be useful.

$$(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i)^t = \sum_{i_1=0}^{t}\sum_{i_2=0}^{i_1}\sum_{i_3=0}^{i_2}\ldots \binom{t}{i_1}\binom{i_1}{i_2}\binom{i_2}{i_3} \ldots x^{i_1+i_2+i_3+\ldots}$$

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to get an analytical continuation to your expression using the gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 ... +x^{\infty}\right)^t=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^t}=(1-x)^{-t}$

The binomial expansion gives
$$(1-x)^{-t}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n x^n \binom{-t}{n}$$
For $t=10$ for instance we have
$$\left(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 ... +x^{\infty}\right)^{10}=1 + 10 x + 55 x^2 + 220 x^3 + 715 x^4 + 2002 x^5 + 5005 x^6 + 
 11440 x^7 + 24310 x^8 + 48620 x^9 + 92378 x^{10}+\ldots$$